# Adjective that are essential qualities of a noun comes before a noun in sentence structure, how do we define essential?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, sintaxis

In this [website](http://www.spanishdict.com/guide/adjective-placement) it is said that

> Descriptive adjectives that emphasize an essential quality of a noun often come before the noun.

For example

> El valiente león protege su territorio.

But can it be argued that most adjective are essential quality?

For example

> Mi hermano es un hombre alto.

Is tall not an essential property of the brother?

Comment: A timid lion would surprise you but a short brother would not. Does that help?

Comment: Hard choice between all three answers, each explains a different aspect of the Asker's question and all are very good and thorough

Answer (score 6):

It's talking about adjectives that are used, not to differentiate or qualify the subject, but just to give some kind of ambience. I like to call these adjectives "poetic adjectives", because they are used mostly to embellish what is being said, nothing more.

Examples:

> Las **verdes** hojas del árbol cantan en el viento.

Tree leaves are usually green. You don't need to be told that, but it helps you form the mental image of a tree.

> La **dulce** miel es deliciosa en pan tostado.

You already know that honey is sweet. It's there just so you can almost *taste* it.

And of course, your example with the lion.

Comment: Also very useful as a starting point.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think “essential” properly defines the semantic function of preposed adjectives. I’d say that preposed adjectives tend to be more subjective while postposed adjectives tend to be more objective and sometimes even restrictive. One of the best examples is “grande”, which as you probably know is abridged before nouns in the singular:

- *gran hombre* can be translated as “great man”, while “hombre grande” means “big man”.

This difference also involves the comparative and superlative:

- *mayor problema* can be translated as “main problem” (with *mayor* reflecting degree of importance), while *hermano mayor* means “elder brother” (where *mayor* refers to age).

We can say that assigning degrees of importance is highly subjective, while describing somebody’s age is quite objective.

A similar case is that of *alto*. When preposed it indicates hierarchy or intensity; when postposed, it denotes size. Thus, *alto comisionado* is "high commissioner", while "comisionado alto" is translated as "tall commissioner".

There are adjectives which will be similar, showing little or no difference when translated into English, whether they are preposed or postposed, for example:

- *altas temperaturas* vs. *temperaturas altas*, where the choice will only be based on stylistic reasons.
- *principal personaje* vs. *personaje principal* (“main character”)

We can also find preposed adjectives that denote size and merely form a set phrase or lexical unit, as is the case with *alta montaña*.

However, preposition will generally sound more subjective (e.g. "principal personaje" may sound like the main character in my opinion), while postposition will render a more objective phrase ("personaje principal" is closer in meaning to the main character in everyone’s opinion, or according to most readers, spectators or critics).

Finally, unlike preposed adjectives, postposed ones can be restrictive, meaning “the one/s that is/are like that” (rather than any others). Thus, *el hombre valiente* (as opposed to *el hombre cobarde*) refers to a particular kind of men, or to an individual man (the one who is brave).

Comment: ..Great answer.